# How to limit the languages that can be detected by Microsoft Translator's detect method

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, language-detection

I am using Microsoft Cognitive Services and the Translator service as part of it.
Translator API supports multiple languages including English, French, Dutch etc.

At times, the same word can be present in multiple languages. So the API randomly returns language 1 or language 2. If I would like it to restrict the languages to be detected to a sub list of languages supported by Microsoft, then how can I do it?

For example, 'hi' is detected at times as language 'sl' instead of 'en', but I want the service to detect only English or French.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Translator](https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai/) for that.

You select a language pair while creating a project, then you submit documents for training, you review and edit the results and repeat the process till the results are satisfying and you’re ready to deploy your model.

You can check the complete guide [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Custom-Translator-Documentation/blob/master/Microsoft%20Translator%20Custom%20Translator%20User%20Guide.pdf)

Comment: Which parameter in Custom Translation allows limiting the number of languages?

Comment: @SHILPAAR You simply select a language pair while creating a project, I’ve updated my answer to include explanation.